# Deploy dll with resource files to sharepoint 2010 in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, resources, sharepoint-2010, gac

I have problem to add a assembly to my sharepoint project. I have a assembly that contains resource files for different language. I have one file for English, Utility.resx och one for Swedish Utility.sv-SE.resx. When I build it, it will be one dll for the project and one for the swedish language. The problem is when I should deploy it to Sharepoint with Visual Studio. I have added the assembly for the project to my packagefile in my sharepoint project. But when I trying to deploy it but I got the message:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: Utility.resources.dll

I have tried to specified both sv-SE\Utility.resources.dll and Utility.resources.dll as Location when I added the assembly i package. Note that I want to add it as assembly from project output.

Anyone having an ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This should help - http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/deploying-localized-satellite-assemblies-with-sharepoint-2010/

You have to add the resource assemblies using **"Add Existing Assembly"** and **hard code the path** to the BIN\release\ folder and NOT "Add Assembly from Project Output" for some reason...

And no - you can't use bin\$(ConfigurationName) -- GAHH!

Comment: For me (VS2012 + SP2013), there was no need to hard code the path (i.e. relative path), but "Add Existing Assembly" was necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Why not deploying the resource files as resx?
They need to be added to the manifest.xml as "RootFiles":

```
<RootFile>
    <RootFile Location="Resources\Utility.sv-SE.resx"></RootFile>
    <RootFile Location="Resources\Utility.resx"></RootFile>
</RootFiles>
```

Hope that helps,
marco